# How can i sum multiple row value in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have this results in attached image, I need the total sum of 122 & 455 from "trans_inventory" column.

```
    trans_id trans_items  trans_user trans_date          trans_comment           trans_inventory location_id
        8236        1488           1 2016-05-02 02:14:35 Manual Edit of Quantity   10.0000000000           1    
        8237        1488           1 2016-05-02 02:15:05 RECV 58                  122.0000000000           1
        8238        1488           1 2016_05-02 02:15:29 RECV 59                  455.0000000000           1
        8239        1488           1 2016-05-02 02:17:32 NEWP- 506                -55.0000000000           1
        8240        1488           1 2016-05-02 02:18:00 NEWP- 507               -121.0000000000           1
```

How can I get it?

sorry for my bad english. maybe, i can't explain well.

Comment: Do you mean only the positive values sum?

Comment: How do you want to do? There are many ways using transid, trans_comment or using transdate. Please explain a bit more how do you want to achieve

Comment: So do you need to group by the `trans_comment` filed?

Comment: i need the sum of 122 & 455. but i don't know how. :(

Comment: post your query how to get the showed result

Comment: @ashish yes i just want the sum of trans_inventory values where trans_comment has like RECV *.

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(trans_inventory) FROM (YOUR_QUERY_OF_RESULT_HERE)x 
WHERE trans_comment LIKE "RECV %"
```

... or when you are using a table:

```
SELECT SUM(trans_inventory) FROM table_name 
WHERE trans_comment LIKE "RECV %"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SUM function:

```
SELECT SUM("trans_inventory") FROM table_name WHERE trans_id = 8237 OR trans_id = 8238;
```

Comment: thanx for reply, but trans_id not static. it will be dynamically, that i won't know.

Comment: Use like 'RECV %' based on your last comment